# Ajuda com Select em duas colunas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, select

Tenho o seguinte comando select:

```
SELECT
pa_coduni,
pa_proc_id,
sum(case when substr(pa_cmp, 1, 4) = 2017 then pa_qtdapr else 0 end) a2017,
sum(case when substr(pa_cmp, 1, 4) = 2018 then pa_qtdapr else 0 end) a2018,
sum(pa_qtdapr) total
FROM
bacabalma
where
substr(pa_cmp, 1, 4) >= 2017
group by
pa_coduni, substr(pa_cmp, 1, 4), pa_proc_id
order by
pa_coduni, pa_proc_id
```

Funciona bem, mas o resultado sai assim:

```
pa_coduni | pa_proc_id | a2017 | a2018 | total
aaa       |aaaa        | 1     | 0     | 1
aaa       |aaaa        | 0     | 1     | 1
```

Como fazer pro resultado vir assim:

```
pa_coduni | pa_proc_id | a2017 | a2018 | total
aaa       |aaaa        | 1     | 1     | 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remova o `substr(pa_cmp, 1, 4)` do `GROUP BY` senão seu resultado será agrupado por ano.

---

> [`GROUP BY Modifiers`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)
>
> The `GROUP BY` clause permits a `WITH ROLLUP` modifier that causes summary output to include extra rows that represent higher-level (that is, super-aggregate) summary operations. `ROLLUP` thus enables you to answer questions at multiple levels of analysis with a single query. For example, `ROLLUP` can be used to provide support for `OLAP (Online Analytical Processing)` operations.
>
> Suppose that a sales table has year, country, product, and profit columns for recording sales profitability:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales(
>   year    INT,
>   country VARCHAR(20),
>   product VARCHAR(32),
>   profit  INT
> );
> ```
>
> To summarize table contents per year, use a simple `GROUP BY` like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT year, SUM(profit) AS profit
>   FROM sales
>  GROUP BY year;
>
> +------+--------+
> | year | profit |
> +------+--------+
> | 2000 |   4525 |
> | 2001 |   3010 |
> +------+--------+
> ```

Em tradução livre:

> A cláusula `GROUP BY` permite um modificador`WITH ROLLUP` que faz com que a saída de resumo inclua linhas extras que representam operações de resumo de nível superior (isto é, super agregadas). O `ROLLUP` permite-lhe responder a questões em múltiplos níveis de análise com uma única consulta. Por exemplo, `ROLLUP` pode ser usado para fornecer suporte para operações`OLAP (Online Analytical Processing)`.
>
> Suponha que uma tabela de vendas tenha colunas de ano, país, produto e lucro para registrar a lucratividade das vendas:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales(
>   year    INT,
>   country VARCHAR(20),
>   product VARCHAR(32),
>   profit  INT
> );
> ```
>
> Para resumir o conteúdo da tabela por ano, use um `GROUP BY` simples assim:
>
> ```
> SELECT year, SUM(profit) AS profit
>   FROM sales
>  GROUP BY year;
>
> +------+--------+
> | year | profit |
> +------+--------+
> | 2000 |   4525 |
> | 2001 |   3010 |
> +------+--------+
> ```